Set up Spark with proxy bypass
I have been trying to setup spark to bypass proxy and i came across the extraJavaOptions config
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("MySparkApp") \
            .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-sharing-spark_2.12:3.1.0") \
            .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dhttp.proxyHost={HOST} -Dhttp.proxyPort={PORT}-            Dhttps.proxyHost={HOST} -Dhttps.proxyPort={PORT} -Dhttps.proxyUser={USERNAME} -Dhttps.proxyPassword={PASSWORD}") \
            .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dhttp.proxyHost={HOST} -Dhttp.proxyPort={PORT}-   Dhttps.proxyHost={HOST} -Dhttps.proxyPort={PORT} -Dhttps.proxyUser={USERNAME} -Dhttps.proxyPassword={PASSWORD}") \
            .getOrCreate()


But this does not seem to bypass the proxy, any other options or is there something i am missing?
Trying to setup spark to bypass proxy
Expectation -> Access data bypassing proxy
Result -> server not found
